# Is there terminology for describing websocket connection types/structures?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm learning about websockets, and I'm having trouble figuring out what you call the types of connections, like if a connection is streaming to everyone connected; if a client inputs any data it will reflect on all other clients. Also I don't even know if this is possible, if a clients connections could be completely independent from other connections but still streaming. what are these connection structures called?

sorry for the poor terminology

Comment: That sounds like multicast.

Comment: yes @barmar I found a wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing#Delivery_schemes, it seems like the idea is like "routing schemes" but with a socket connections. only thing is if i google search for unicast websockets nothing not much shows up. I wonder if there another name for it

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/websockets/#websocket